# Thread of a member function

Tags: c++

Mainly for test purposes,

I want to run a member function on a thread.

Endless tries - and still, only error messages,

Please - can anyone explain the cause of the error and some best practices of doing so?
Thanks

[image]

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    int x = 1;
    int y = 7;
    int a() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            x += y;
           cout << "x:" << x << endl;
        }
        return x;
    }
    int b() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            y -= 0.5 * x;
            cout << "y:" << y << endl;
        }
        return y;
    }
    Test() {

    }
    Test* run() {
        thread(&Test::a, this);
        //thread(&Test::b, this);
        return this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test* obj = new Test();
    obj->run();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider reading about [`std::thread::join()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join).

Comment: it blocks until a specified thread dies, am I right? does it solve the error somehow?

Comment: It does. `abort()` is called because a temporary `std::thread` object is destructed before it is joined or detached.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: you will also need to synchronize access to shared variables with a `mutex` or by using `std::atomic` for `x` and `y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `std::thread` object lives only until the end of the expression in which it is created as a temporary. When it is destroyed and the thread is still in a joinable state, `std::terminate` is called, which aborts your program.

You should store the `std::thread` object somewhere (e.g. in the `Test` object or in `main` or locally in `run`) and call `.join()` on it at the correct time where you expect the thread to finish (e.g. destructor or before the end of `main` or at the end of `run`).

---

Aside from that, if you run the out-commented thread as well, you have data races causing undefined behavior. You may not access non-atomic objects (such as `x` and `y`) in multiple threads without synchronization if at least one of these accesses is a write.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the race conditions :) I did not realize an error arises when there is no call for join.

Comment: @Daniel Data races, not race conditions. The latter is ok, but has potentially unspecified results. The former is undefined behavior. If you change the variable type to `std::atomic<int>` you downgrade to a race condition.